# then() function in angular2

Tags: angular

In angular quickstart I find a code as

```
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
```

.then has 3 parameters in it. What do they stand for? Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Actually its only 2 parameters ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then))

In your example you have only one:

```
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(function(heroes) {
          this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5)
    });
```

First parameter is for *resolve* callback   - executes if we have **success** result

Second parameter is for *reject* callback   - executes if something goes wrong (**fail**)

Also there are two reasons why people using `=>`

1. It shorter (sort of syntax sugar)
2. It does not create own *this* referrence

Comment: The whole code is as follows:
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
        }

So does it mean this.heroService.getHeroes() is called and whatever is returned from it is assigned to heroes variable and then we slice few elements from it and assign it to this.heroes variable. Am i correct?

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot :)